# How to get count of all entries after sorting and keep only unique entries in bash?

Tags: bash, sorting, unique

I have a big text file with repeating entries so i am using sorting and keeping only unique entries in my output file by using following command:

```
sort -u bigfile.txt > uniqueentry.txt
```

I want to keep count of all the unique entries i tried to use -c as follows:

```
sort -u -c bigfile.txt > uniqueentry.txt
```

It didn't work, Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: How about: `sort file | uniq -c > uniques_with_count.txt`

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want.

If you want to count the total number of unique entries, you can do it like this:

```
sort -u bigfile.txt | wc -l
```

If you want to count how many of each unique entry was in the original file, then:

```
sort bigfile.txt | uniq -c
```